# Modal button is not working in dash python

Tags: python-3.x, button, plotly-dash

I want to place the button on the graph1 designed below.However the 'Open modal' button is not working when clicked.I have the below codes :-

```
app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': 'black'}, children=[
     html.H1('This is the header',style={'textAlign': 'center','color': 'yellow','font-family': 'Quicksand','font_size': '50px'}),
     html.Div(id='div1',style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block','background_color':'black'}, children=[            
     dbc.Button("Open modal", id="open"),
     dbc.Modal(
         [
             dbc.ModalHeader("Header"),
             dbc.ModalBody("This is the content of the modal"),
             dbc.ModalFooter(
                 dbc.Button("Close", id="close", className="ml-auto")
             ),
         ],
         id="modal",
    ),
 dcc.Graph(id='graph1', figure={'layout':layout},style={'display':'none'})])])
    
    
    @app.callback(
        Output("modal-sm", "is_open"),
        [Input("open-sm", "n_clicks"), Input("close-sm", "n_clicks")],
        [State("modal", "is_open")],
        )
    def toggle_modal(n1, n2, is_open):
        if n1 or n2:
            return not is_open
        return is_open
```

Could you please suggest if anythong going wrong here?

Comment: Could you post the complete code? Otherwise, it is had to debug your issue.

Comment: The inputs for your callback are elements with `id=open-sm` and `id=close-sm`. Should these instead be `id=open` and `id=close` to match the `id`s of the two buttons?

Answer (score 0):

As ncasale stated the ids in your callback do not match the ids of the modal button. In addition the State 'modal' should be changed to 'modal-sm'

Please see below your code with the above corrections:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': 'black'}, children=[
     html.H1('This is the header',style={'textAlign': 'center','color': 'yellow','font-family': 'Quicksand','font_size': '50px'}),
     html.Div(id='div1',style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block','background_color':'black'}, children=[            
     dbc.Button("Open modal", id="open-sm"),
     dbc.Modal(
         [
             dbc.ModalHeader("Header"),
             dbc.ModalBody("This is the content of the modal"),
             dbc.ModalFooter(
                 dbc.Button("Close", id="close-sm", className="ml-auto")
             ),
         ],
         id="modal-sm",
    ),
    #dcc.Graph(id='graph1', figure={'layout':layout},style={'display':'none'})
    ])])
    
    
@app.callback(
    Output("modal-sm", "is_open"),
    [Input("open-sm", "n_clicks"), Input("close-sm", "n_clicks")],
    [State("modal-sm", "is_open")],
    )
def toggle_modal(n1, n2, is_open):
    if n1 or n2:
        return not is_open
    return is_open


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```